# Javascript Read Mime Type CSV Always Empty

Tags: javascript, windows, csv, chromium

I'm currently struggling with Windows Browser to check mimetype of a `csv` file. I've tried checking it via:

```
console.log($('#file')[0].files[0].type); // output: ""
```

But when I use Linux browser, it works fine:

```
console.log($('#file')[0].files[0].type); // output: "text/csv"
```

How could this happen? Is there any alternative solution for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my Windows + browser spec:

- Chromium 50.0.2632.0
- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

### Update 1

When I tried to upload a `jpg` / `png` / any image file, Chromium can detect it's mime-type.

> I'm sorry, English is not my native.

Comment: When you say "Windows browser" are you using Chromium as well, or Internet Explorer?

Comment: I don't have IE on my Windows. I use `Edge` but still, it returns an empty string.

Comment: we too are facing the same problem. In my windows pc, im getting 'application/vnd.ms-excel' as mime-type for csv file, but 2 of my peers are getting empty "".  Not sure what is causing this issue. it cannot specific to browser but could be related to Environment as all 3 of us are using Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The mime-type is set by the browser depending on what it extensions it "knows" about. Internet Explorer doesn't have the mime-type for .csv [see this list here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(v=vs.85).aspx). I would just check for .csv file extension manually on IE. Or you could use an external library that knows more than IE does.

Ultimately what gets placed in file.type is set by the browser. You will need to check the extension manually with either a library (I couldn't find one), or a switch statement such as [this suggestion](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/160968/How-to-get-Content-MIME-Type-of-the-Uploaded-File-in-jQuery-Uploadify-Plugin-in-ASPNet/).

You can look up a list of mime-types and just add the ones you think you will encounter.

**EDIT**

The browser also supplies the FileReader object. You can use that to check things client-side. With Javascript being single threaded, I have no idea how well it would handle large files though. [Here is a link.](http://www.javascripture.com/FileReader#readAsText_Blob_String)

Comment: Actually my client agreed to use Google Chrome / Chrome / any WebKit-based browsers. In other words, they willing to not use IE. The problem is, Chromium or Google Chrome cannot detect csv mime-type.

Comment: Thanks mate. Really appreciate it. As your suggestion, maybe I have to upload it to server and check whether it's a valid CSV file (maybe AFAIK javascript in Windows cannot handle this, or maybe just a misconfiguration issue somewhere).

Comment: Serverside has a lot more options for this issue, at least according to all the sources I checked.

Comment: You can also check the magic bits at the beginning of the file to check mimetype, but you have to be careful because a standard text file renamed as .csv could be perfectly valid.

Comment: I've tried this solution. It works, but as you said, it's not good when user wants to upload huge files.

Comment: So this also happens with HEIF/HEIC files if you drop them onto say, Firefox on Windows. Apparently the fox knows nothing about these "obscure" formats 

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is - if you have Microsoft office, then your browsers will work just fine and will see csv type, if you don't have it - it won't

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

`File.Type` is resolved on the basis of client configuration. If `.csv` is not configured at the client configuration then it will return an empty string.

The explanation to this issue is present on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724649/mime-type-of-file-returning-empty-in-javascript-on-some-machines).

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe that's a bug on chrome or win 10. I have use OS and browser just like you. But when I import it on Firefox it has show file type. Here is 2 browser I had checked

- Chrome

[image]

- Firefox

[image]

p/s: I have faced with a problem that I just want users just only import CSV file. But in chrome the file type have empty so I don't have a condition here to check it.