# MIME type of file returning empty in javascript on some machines

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript snippet written which checks for the mime type of the files.

`var type = this.files[0].type;`

Code was running fine for a long time but now somehow its not able to find value of file type.

I checked in browser's debug tool and find mime type of file is blank.

Issues is happening on some machines only and running fine on others,
although both machines are running on **Windows 10** and using same version of **google chrome** (version 68.0.3440.84).

Any idea?

Comment: Please share your code as a [mcve] I can't seem to reproduce the issue

Comment: Hi @Luca, even the issue is not reproducible on my machine and happening on few QA machines only.
You can try this fiddle as this is also not working on QA machine but working on my machine:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FN94CWIgYpB63f9PrQSk?p=preview

Comment: Are there any errors on those machines? I have the same Version of Chrome and Win10  and it's working with no problems? Maybe try reinstalling Chrome and not signing in, it may be some extensions

Comment: There is no error on server or client side. I don't think issue is browser specific as, issue is reproducible on firefox as well with same machines :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally, i got the answer for my question and here is reason why this was happening on some machines.

As i was expecting, issue is system specific where content-type for .csv type is missing under Registry (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.csv).

See screenshot, This entry was missing on some machines.

[image: This was missing on some machines]

Comment: Thank you! This helped me to find out what was going on. Just to include something else, I found that ["Client configuration (for instance, the Windows Registry) may result in unexpected values even for common types. Developers are advised not to rely on this property as a sole validation scheme."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type#Example)

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem with csv files with my Angular 8 application.
The problem is **only** on the machine where Excel is not installed, so the `csv` key in the registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is missing, as said by *money* user up here.