# React Dropzone not able to accept certain file types

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

In my create-react-app, App.js, I have these file types, which is always rejected.

```
xls - application/x-msi
pptm - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
pptx - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
xlsm - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
rtf - application/rtf
```

[Full code](https://github.com/kenpeter/test_formik):

```
import React, {useCallback} from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';

const docUploadConfig = {
  fileTypes: [
    'application/pdf',
    'application/msword',
    'application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',

    // excel
    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12',
    'application/msexcel',
    'application/x-msexcel',
    'application/x-ms-excel',
    'application/x-excel',
    'application/x-dos_ms_excel',
    'application/xls',
    'application/x-xls',
    'application/x-msi',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',

    'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
    'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
    'text/plain',
    'text/xml',

    'application/xml',

    'text/html',
    'application/rtf',
    'text/csv',
    'image/tiff',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/png',
    'image/gif',
    'image/bmp',
    'application/x-afp',
    'application/vnd.ibm.modcap'
  ],
  minSize: 0,
  maxSize: 2097152,
  isMultipleFiles: false
};

function MyDropzone() {
  const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
    // Do something with the files

    console.log('accept', acceptedFiles);
    console.log('reject', rejectedFiles);
  }, []);
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: docUploadConfig.fileTypes.join(',')
    //accept: 'application/rtf'
  });

  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {isDragActive ? (
        <p>Drop the files here ...</p>
      ) : (
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyDropzone />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In summary:

1. is it a way to make it working react drop zone?
2. is it a more reliable way to tell what file types are, when **onDrop**

Comment: Hey, encountering these questions now, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if you do not have Microsoft Office installed on the machine then Microsoft Office documents are not generally recognised by JavaScript.

[MIME type of file returning empty in javascript on some machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724649/mime-type-of-file-returning-empty-in-javascript-on-some-machines)

Once I installed Microsoft Office on my machine, it seems there are some registry updates which actually allow JavaScript to recognise these filetypes, and then the uploader works as required.

However, in a real world scenario this is not ideal, as you can not guarantee all of your users will have Microsoft Office installed, but still might have received files from say a friend/colleague they want to upload via the uploader.

So, our workaround for this is to actually not use the allowed functionality built into the react-dropzone, and instead handle everything on the backend, and just allow everything on the frontend.

Learn More : https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/991#issuecomment-664256221