# Problem validating audio file in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, file-upload, mime-types, jquery-file-upload

I want to use Javascript to prevent users from uploading any file except audio files. For example: MP3 only.

This code works on the desktop and some phones but on some older phones it gives an error when I upload MP3.

```js
$("#track-file").change(function(e) {
  var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
  if (file.type !== 'audio/mpeg') {
    $('#track-file-error').html('* The file must be Audio');
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="track-file" name="track-file" accept=".mp3">
```

Comment: And what error is that?

Comment: This means that the same error that I bet is displayed and says that the file is not MP3 while the file is MP3

Comment: What is the `file.type` of that file? E.g. `console.log(file.type);`

Comment: Because console.log is not inside the mobile. I showed the file type inside a paragraph that plays audio / mpeg on the desktop, but inside the mobile it is null

Comment: This might be relevant: "Client configuration (for instance, the Windows Registry) may result in unexpected values even for common types. Developers are advised not to rely on this property as a sole validation scheme," ([File.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type)). Also, `type` is not supported in Firefox or Opera for Android. Could either of these be impacting your results? See [MIME type of file returning empty in JavaScript on some machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724649/mime-type-of-file-returning-empty-in-javascript-on-some-machines).