# How to know file type in file object when type property is empty

Tags: javascript, angular, file, ionic-framework

I'm reading a file in android application with:

```
<ion-input type="file" (change)="readFile($event)"></ion-input>
```

I get a `file` object, and I can know the file type by checking the `type` property.

But some files have empty `type` property, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

How can I konw the file type if it has empty `type` property and no extension?

Comment: Why not just tell the user "unknown file type" and let the user figure it out ?

Comment: This is for an android app, so I test it in my own phone and I found out that almost all audio files have no type, so I will need to ask the user about almost all files. In addition, what if the user tell me that this is an audio file but actually this is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that I find is to convert it to base64, for example with this code:

```
getBase64(file)
  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
      const reader = this.getFileReader();// this function is important for real devices. Without it the fielReader.onload will not be triggered in read device
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
  }
```

the return will look like that:

```
'data:application/octet-stream;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACqCBoIBE09wdXNIZWFkAQFoAIA+AAAAAABPZ2dTAAAAAAAAAAA ...
```

As you can see, after `data:` we get the `type`. In this case `application/octet-stream`

Comment: Hm but won't the type just simply be always `application/octet-stream` when it was unknown before? Since that's basically a "catch-all" type for "some kind of data that we don't know anything specific about"...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while ago, when using a Windows machine.
Fixed the issue following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51741557/16697539).

To quote: "As i was expecting, issue is system specific where content-type for .csv type is missing under Registry (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.csv)."

Comment: This appears to be a link only answer.  You should post the parts that support your answer, in case the link disappears later.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesEF, roger that. I've added more details to my answer.

Comment: Thanks but my question is about android device so it doesn't help me